# Using artifacts from an upstream pipeline in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

The GitLab documentation mentions the use of `needs:project` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsproject) to specify a project (and branch or whatever) from which to get the artifacts, but "the artifacts are downloaded from the latest successful specified job for the specified ref".

This looks really wrong for the case of an upstream pipeline triggering a downstream pipeline. The latter should not depend (and download) on "the latest successful" artifacts, but the artifacts from the specific pipeline that triggered the current one.

Am I misinterpreting something? Is there some way to get it right (i.e. to download the artifacts from the correct pipeline/job, and not just from whatever happens to be latest)?

Comment: Have you found a way to achieve this? I saw some examples using the old API to get the artifacts from the correct pipeline...

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to achieve it with multi-project pipelines.

### Upstream Project A

```
# Job to trigger the pipeline of the downstream project and send the 
downstream:
needs:
    - job: job-creating-the-artifact
variables:
    PARENT_COMMIT_REF_NAME: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
trigger: your/downstream/projectB
```

`$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is the branch or tag name for which project is built. [Predefined CI/CD variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

### Downstream Project B

```
test:
stage: test
script:
  - echo 'Fetching artifcats from upstream pipeline'
needs:
  - project: your/upstream/projectA
    job: build
    ref: $PARENT_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    artifacts: true
```

With this approach, you get the artifacts from the must recent pipeline/job pf the commit.

The dependencies could look like that:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? According the the documentation and my tests (at that time, about 1 year ago), that does not refer to any specific pipeline, just to the "latest successful" pipeline. If you run two pipelines in project A (upstream), let them finish, now go to the project B (downstream) job belonging to the first (oldest) pipeline and re-run it, will it take the artifacts from the first A job, or from the second (latest)?

Comment: You are correct it takes it from the second project. I missed that :/

Comment: @Jellby But to be fair if you make the upstream trigger wait for the job creating the artifacts it works quite ok. And yeah I found this GitLab issue which is still open describing the problem https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/373053

Comment: Updated my answer to wait for the artifact to be present